# 28V SMPS Supply correction LED

Tags: power-supply, led, current, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply

I want to put an LED to see that the input of my LTM8053 SMPS circuit is operational. I have 28V input. I'm thinking of putting 1206 package SMD LEDs, but I'm not sure either. I think it is not enough to make a selection based on the current passing through the LED. Can you help with this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: `Can you help with this?` is not a question about the LED circuit ... please ask a question about the circuit

Comment: Unclear what you mean. Do you need an input voltage indication LED? Power supply OK indication LED? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

The *only* thing you have to select (assuming the LED type is selected) is the current through the LED. From that follows power dissipation calculations for the dropping resistor, and, of course, the resistor value.

And with 28V you don't need to worry too much about Vf of the LED, you can use 2V or 3V.

The only comment I have on the selection is not to fall into the trap of using the maximum LED current. Often 2 or 3mA results in an LED that is plenty bright enough, so more like 10kΩ would be suitable. Your current with 1.8kΩ will result in more like 15mA, and the resistor will dissipate more than 1/3 of a watt, so it will have to be relatively large (and will waste a lot of power).